# Using Values of an Angular Controller in Two Different Pages

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, controller

I have two different pages. Let's their names are `product.php` and `buy.php.`
I have a `controllerProduct` for `product.php` and `controllerBuy` for `buy.php`.

A user loads `product.php` and selects a product to buy which price is 59$. When he or she selects the product, the `$scope.setPrice();` function runs in `controllerProduct`. The setPrice function be like:

```
window.ngApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
window.ngApp.controller('controllerProduct', ['$scope',
     function ($scope) {
          $scope.price = null //default
          $scope.setPrice = function(){
               $scope.price = 59;
          }; 
}]);
```

Now he or she selected the product which price is 59$ and finaly clicked the buy button and `buy.php` page will be loaded.

In `buy.php` I want to show the user something like this:

"Hey user, you are going to buy this product! And its price is `{{price}}$`".

How can I use the price variable from controllerProduct in controllerBuy?

Comment: you simply just need to save price's data on browser storage. so, you can retrieve it on another page.

Answer (score 0):

everytime you want to share logic between controllers it's a perfect scenario for a service.

A general approach could be this

```
 //singleton to share logic between controllers
.service('ShareService', function(){
 var _price = null;
 this.setPrice = function(price){
   _price = price; 
 }
 this.getPrice = function(){
   return _price;
 }
})

 //first controller
.controller('controllerProduct', function($scope, ShareService){
  $scope.setPrice = function(price){
    $scope.price = price;
    ShareService.setPrice(price);
  }; 
})

//second controller
.controller('controllerBuy', function($scope, ShareService){
  //watch changes of the price
  $scope.$watch(function(){
    return ShareService.getPrice()
  }, function(newVal){
    $scope.selectedPrice = newVal;
  })
})
```

Comment: On product.php page product.js loads which has controllerProduct, on buy.php page buy.js loads which has controllerBuy. Where do I put the shareService ?

Comment: you can create a different file